# Copiar archivo google dirve php error autenticación

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive

Estoy intentado crear un codigo que copie un archivo existente y una vez lo copie lo comparta con mi cuenta (desde una cuenta de servicio), cuando ejecuto el codigo me sale lo siguiente:

```
Please visit: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&access_type=online&client_id='id'&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&state&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&approval_prompt=auto Please enter the auth code:
```

Y me lleva a una pagina de google que me pide autenticacion OAtuh 2.0, pero ya tengo un archivo con esos requisitos referenciado en el codigo, alguien sabe porque puede ser??

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=archivo.json');

$apiKEY="api_key";
$client = new Google\Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']);

private function copy_base_file( $new_file_name )
{
$service = $this->get_google_service_drive( $this->get_google_client() );
$origin_file_id = "id_carpeta";
$copiedFile = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$copiedFile->setName('prueba');

try {
    $response = $service->files->copy($origin_file_id, $copiedFile);
    $ownerPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
    $ownerPermission->setEmailAddress("correo");
    $ownerPermission->setType('user');
    $ownerPermission->setRole('owner');
    $service->permissions->create("id_carpeta", $ownerPermission, 
        ['emailMessage' => 'You added a file to ' .
        static::$applicationName . ': ' . "Does this work"]);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Pues eso, google no te deja hacer esas cosas sin autenticarte BIEN, es decir, con OAuth (mostrando el login en pantalla y todo eso). Tener unas credenciales guardadas no es OAuth. Entonces, o creas un application password  para esa cuenta o cambias la autenticada con google. Hazle caso al mensaje que te está dando

Comment: Esto me muestra `Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request, urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob, can only be used by a Client ID for native application. It is not allowed for the WEB client type. You can create a Client ID for native application at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient
`

Comment: Pero el arhivo .json de autenticación no puede ser lo que este mal, ya que lo estoy usando para otro código y si funciona

Comment: No necesitas OAuth para conectarte con una Cuenta de Servicio (ojo, algunas APIs no admiten Cuentas de Servicio, pero no es el caso de la API de Drive). Lo que debes cuidar es que la misma esté creada correctamente, que tenga los permisos necesarios, que la API de Drive esté habilitada para ese proyecto, que hayas descargado el `.json` correcto y que en el código PHP pongas la ubicación correcta de dicho archivo `.json`. Luego, escribe tu código de conexión como se indica en los ejemplos ([ver aquí](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-service-accounts)).

Comment: [Este es un PHP completo de conexión con Cuenta de Servicio](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/main/examples/service-account.php). Pero OJO, ese ejemplo es de la API de Google Books, solamente adapta las clases y los scopes, poniendo los de  Drive.